# Wireshark bluetooth traffic extraction and analysis

Tags: networking, bluetooth, protocols, wireshark, editcap

I'm quite a beginner to Wireshark and I got problem using it, I searched the wireshark wiki but seems no promising results. Hopefully I can get some help here.

I am trying to analyze the network traffic between LG smart watch and Android phone, which all go through bluetooth channel. Now I have got the network traffic log file and I can view it by running `wireshark <log_file_name>`. Problem is how can I extract and retrieve data, or even just remove the bluetooth header and get the `original network layer packet`, because I can parse the IP layer packet but bluetooth packet is not what I want and what I understand.

Comment: the log file can be accessed here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxINm19KyB6raTZVZ2lpb2dzZnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: actually bluetooth just remove the ethernet header and add its own header with the remaining payload unchanged. but still i have no idea how to do the extraction.